# What is the equivalent method in iOS for setImageNamed

Tags: ios10

What is the equivalent method for setImagedNamed for iPhone development. I understand this is an api for watch kit but what is the equivalent method for the iPhone. Thank you for your help with this.

```
@IBAction func rockChosen(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

   watchChoice.image = UIImage(options[randomNumber])
```

It is now giving me an error of  Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [String]' (aka 'inout Array')
How can I correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
watchChoice.image = UIImage(named: options[randomNumber])
```